# NDB: What happens when 1/s write is exceeded?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am evauating how to use GAE + NDB for a new project, and got concerned with the limit of 1 write per second for ancestor writes. I might be missing information, so I'm happy to ask for help.

Say several users work with orders. If all new "order" entities have the same unique ancestor, what would happen if say 5 users each create a new order and all 5 hit "save" at the same time?

Do you know what the consecuences could be?

Thanks!

Comment: One of these will go through, while the others will fail. Putting all new entities under a common ancestor is a good way to get a ton of contention errors

Comment: @Patrice - This is not exactly the case. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your use case, nothing bad would happen - all of your writes will succeed. Some of them may be retried internally by the App Engine, but you should not worry about that. You should only get concerned when you expect this rate to be exceeded for a substantial period of time. Then retries would come on top of previous retries and commits may start failing. Giving your example, you will probably need a few million people working on those orders like crazy before it becomes an issue.

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> The first type of timeout occurs when you attempt to write to a single
>   entity group too quickly. Writes to a single entity group are
>   serialized by the App Engine datastore, and thus there's a limit on
>   how quickly you can update one entity group. In general, this works
>   out to somewhere between 1 and 5 updates per second; a good guideline
>   is that you should consider rearchitecting *if you expect an entity
>   group to have to sustain more than one update per second for an
>   extended period*.

Comment: Hi Andrei, thanks for your answer, it wiped away my concerns. In my case we would never get so many users banging simultaneously at the entities with the same ancestor.